# Managing Mac users

Tags: macos, mobile-device-management, group

I'm managing a group of MacBook users.

Currently, the users are not allowed to install apps or change stuff without administrators involvement.
I would like to have the users to be able to do certain stuff themselves without my involvement.

Like adding a printer or changing certain specific stuff in the control panel.

Is this something that's possible with certain software? Or is there a Gatekeeper way of solving this? (command line trick perhaps)

And on what level can I control such things for a group?

Answer (score 1):

Let them control everything, give them login access to network services etc and their own responsibility for backups.

Then if there is an issue you just install the latest "standard" image and they sort the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, it’s the obvious answer, so why not take a look at Jamf Pro? It’s not free, but it does everything you want and more. You can set policies for individual machines or groups, run scripts, create users, add printers, push preferences, and much more. There is even a Self Service app that allows you to provide apps, settings, printers, etc. that the user can install themselves at the press of a button. And you can determine which users or machines have access to which apps in there.

It’s a very powerful system, and can be run on-premises on your own server, or in the cloud and thus be available to machines even when they are not on your company network.

(I’m only suggesting this as a happy customer. I have no affiliation with Jamf.)

Comment: [JAMF Now](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/) it is pretty powerful, and the best part: **Manage your first three devices for free. Add more starting at just $2/device/month.** We use JAMF Pro to manage our large fleet of iPads and MBAs, but if you have a small number of devices, JAMF Now may just be what your looking for.